# Function Getting null from useNavigation with useLocation on Live Server

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm passing the function using useNavigate, and getting that function into another component but it's getting null. Everything working fine on the local machine and the variable from useNaviagte is working fine but on a live server, it's not working.

Note: My react-router-dom version is ^6.4.2

Code from source component :

```
navigate("/confirmationScreen", {
      state: {
        confirmFunction: handleCreateTransaction,
        redirect: "/wallet",
      },
 });
```

Code from another component where I'm using that function:

```
const {state} = useLocation();
state.confirmFunction;
```

state.confirmFunction getting null

Minimal Example to reproduce error (it working on local machine getting null on production):

1st component:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();
  const proceed = () => {
    navigate("/confirmationScreen", {
      state: {
        confirmFunction: handleCreateTransaction,
        redirect: "/wallet",
      },
    });
  };
  <button onClick={proceed}>Process</button>
```

2nd Component:

```
  import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
  const location = useLocation();
  location.state.confirmFunction // getting null on production
```

Comment: Functions are not JSON/string serializable, so they can't be passed via route state. What is the use case you are trying to solve for here by passing a function? In other words, what is the purpose of `confirmFunction`?

Comment: @DrewReese I'm handling 2FA here, passing the function to the authentication screen, once the user authenticates using the password then the confirm function (any API handler) will run. Actually, I need to handle this function globally in the app with persistence without using local storage.

Comment: Can you share a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] for what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I'm adding the minimal example here, but the function is passing using react-router correctly on the local machine, but it getting null on production.

Comment: It should work the same anywhere the code runs, and I wouldn't expect to be able to pass a function in route state at all anywhere as functions are not JSON serializable. Is `handleCreateTransaction` not a function? This isn't a [mcve] if it's (a) unclear what any part of the code is, and (b) isn't enough code for anyone to easily reproduce an issue.

Comment: @DrewReese I edited the Question, handleCreateTransaction is a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249417/discussion-between-haider-ali-and-drew-reese).